# How to read values and assign variables to them from text file using scanner?

Tags: java

This is my text file "demo.txt". I have to read value value and assign variables like rule for Success, object for product...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file=new File("demo.txt");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(file);
        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            String rule=s.next();
            System.out.println(rule);
        }
    }
}
```

Here if just want the rule Success to be printed what to do then:

> Success
>   product

If the price of the product is greater than 100 and quantity less than 2 and category is "grocery" then
   print the discount equal to 100
Then display the discount is 100

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I have tried, the problem comes when i read the values all the values are read at once. I want them separated.

Comment: So show your code, what you've tried, and where your problem is.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add more detail to your question. Do not use  the comments to add information to the question. Without more information people will not be able to help you and answer the question. We are still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * Java program to read file using Scanner class in Java.
 * java.util.Scanner is added on Java 5 and offer convenient method to read data
 *
 * @author
 */
public class ScannerExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
        File text = new File("C:/temp/test.txt");

        //Creating Scanner instnace to read File in Java
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

        //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
            lineNumber++;
        }      

    }  

}
```

Read more: http://www.java67.com/2012/11/how-to-read-file-in-java-using-scanner-example.html#ixzz4fWXsFF00

Comment: Yes this helped. But i want the values at different line to be assigned to variables.